# Windows 7 X64 unidentified network and public

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I have two interfaces that are built from VMware workstation VMware network adapter vmnet1 and vmnet8. I am unable to change the network location from public to home. The public network options isn't click-able.

Comment: Why do you need to? Mine are all public and I don't have any issues with teams, host only, NAT and direct connection. Maybe update your question with what the problem is with your VM communications.

Comment: yeah, actually things are working ok, I just dont understand whats preventing me from changing it, even if i just wanted to??

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to be able to change the name of the network and adapters as well as configure the other settings. You can click on the icon, but then the name and icon are also locked like the network type. Even clicking on *Merge or Delete Network Locations* does not help because the VMWare network is not listed.